# Estimating $\beta_o$ and $\beta_1$ with Weighted Least Squares with Logit link

Tags: statistics, regression, estimation, least-squares

I showed that $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ must satisfy:

$$\sum w_i\hat\beta_0+\sum w_ix_i\hat\beta_1=\sum w_iy_i$$
and
$$\sum w_ix_i\hat\beta_0+\sum w_ix_i^2\hat\beta_1=\sum w_i x_i y_i$$

I need to fit a model where $r_i/n_i$ is the proportion dead at dose $d_i$. Let $x_i=\log d_i$,$1/w_i=\operatorname{Var}(Y_i)$ and $$p_i=\frac{r_i+1/2}{n_i+1}$$

I also showed that $\operatorname{logit}(p_i)$ has expectation $\operatorname{logit}(\theta_i)=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i$ and variance $\frac{1}{n\theta_i(1-\theta_i)}$
Approximated variance of $w_i=np_i(1-p_i)$

> Now I need to estimate $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$

**My attempt:**

What are the fitted values : $y_i$? They are $\operatorname{logit}(p_i)$, the observed proportions. Now I need to fit a least square line with axis $\operatorname{logit}(p_i)$ against $x_i$.

Rearranging the estimates I have:

$$\hat\beta_0=\frac{\sum w_iy_i-\sum w_ix_i\hat\beta_1}{\sum w_i}$$ and
$$\hat\beta_1=\frac{\sum w_i x_i y_i-\sum w_ix_i\hat\beta_0}{\sum w_ix_i^2}$$

Now I don't know how to proceed, do I need to put summs inside summs or is there an easy way?

**What will the plotted line be?** Is it the expected proportion of deaths $Y$ given some dose best supported by our data?

**EDIT:I know it's a horrible expression, but is it valid?**

Can I simply say:

$$\hat\beta_1=\frac{\sum w_i x_i y_i-n\frac{\sum w_iy_i-\sum w_ix_i\hat\beta_1}{\sum w_i}\sum w_ix_i}{\sum w_ix_i^2}$$

Simplifying:

$$\hat\beta_1-n\frac{\sum w_ix_i \sum w_ix_i\hat\beta_1}{\sum w_i\sum w_ix_i^2} =\frac{\sum w_i x_i y_i-n\frac{\sum w_iy_i}{\sum w_i}\sum w_ix_i}{\sum w_ix_i^2}$$

And again:
$$\hat\beta_1(1-n\frac{\sum w_ix_i \sum w_ix_i}{\sum w_i\sum w_ix_i^2}=\frac{\sum w_i x_i y_i-n\frac{\sum w_iy_i}{\sum w_i}\sum w_ix_i}{\sum w_ix_i^2}$$

Comment: It seems like you try to derive the coefficients of multinomial logistic regression using the (re)WLS approach. May be [this](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/402/lectures/14-logistic-regression/lecture-14.pdf) lecture may somehow help you.

Comment: Ive read it, they fit a model using maximum likelihood and iterate to find the MLE of $\beta$. But i want to fit a least square model. If i understood correctly

Comment: Will what I added at the bottom work?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, MLE and (re)WLS should be the same where there is no technical problems (strict convexity, etc). Generally it seems OK, but you shouldn't rely on this. You may consider to check the results numerically...

Comment: Note that when you write \operatorname{logit} instead of \mathm{logit}, then you get proper spacing in $a\operatorname{logit} b$ and $a\operatorname{logit}(b)$.  I'm showing you two different examples so you can see the context-dependent nature of the spacing. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y = X\beta+\epsilon,$ and $var(Y_i)=1/w_i$ and $cov(Y_i, Y_j)=0$, then $cov(Y)=\sigma^2 \times diag(1/w_1,...,1/w_n)$, as such the "correction" $V^{-1/2}$ matrix should be of the form $V^{-1/2}=diag(\sqrt{w_i},...,\sqrt{w_i})$ because now
$$
cov(V^{-1/2}Y)=V^{-1/2}cov(Y)V^{-1/2}=\sigma^2 I.
$$ 
Therefore, the WLS will be 
$$
\beta_{WLS} = (X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}y,
$$
where $V^{-1} =diag(w_1,...,w_n)$ and $X$ is the usual design matrix of a form $X=[\mathbb{\vec{1}}, \mathbb{\vec{x}}]$. After some algebra you should get
$$
\beta_{WLS} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum w_i & \sum x_iwi\\
\sum x_iw_i & \sum x_i^2w_i
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum w_iy_i\\
\sum x_iw_iy_i
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I guess you can compare it to your final result to reassure the calculations.

Comment: I was looking over this question again and couldn't understand what $\operatorname{cov} Y$ was. I thought it should not have $\sigma^2$, using wiki, $\operatorname{cov} Y=\operatorname{var} Y$ but we know that $\operatorname{var}Y=diag(1/w_i,...,1/w_n)$

Comment: I just took a little more general case with multiplicative constant $\sigma^2$, You can set it to be equal to one. It does not effect the calculations.